# keras binary classifier is predicting same outcome and has very poor AUC

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, predictive-modeling

I tried to build a binary classifier for a dataset with 298 binary factors and 1 predictive binary outcome, but the predicted values for the test data are all the same. My code is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('gwas.csv')
X = df.drop(['GWAS','snpID','chr','pos', 'rsID'], axis = 1)
y = df['GWAS']

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_dim = 298),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
])

model.compile('sgd',  loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])

hist = model.fit(X, y, epochs=40, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.2)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred
```

I get

```
array([[0.5462529],
       [0.5462529],
       [0.5462529],
       ...,
       [0.5462529],
       [0.5462529],
       [0.5462529]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Avoid using a `ReLU` activation when there's a `sigmoid` activation at the output layer. I have discussed the reason in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71633256/13546426) answer.